# How to make an angular app accessible both on localhost and host.docker.internal?

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, network-programming

An angular app running in the browser makes backend API requests. The URL of these requests is determined by concatenating the **protocol + domain + port** specified in the corresponding `environment-*.ts` file and a **path**.

The protocol + domain + port part can be 'overridden' using a [proxy](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server). However, this can be done only when we `ng serve` the app. Once we `ng build`, these are hardwired into the `./dist` artifacts.

Now consider a `staging` configuration. Ideally, the protocol + domain + port would be `http://localhost:4200`. This way anybody can run the entire web app locally. If the frontend, backend, and database services are all specified in a `docker-compose.yml` file, one can start and stop the whole thing (swarm?) using a single command. No need to play with system files, such as `/etc/hosts`.

Enter e2e tests. These tests need their own JVM, headless browser, and other dependencies. So they too come in a docker image. However, from their perspective, `localhost` is different from our `localhost`. All they see is the loopback address of their container. There are [two ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/1097451) to allow these e2e tests to access the app on the correct `localhost`:

1. Start the e2e tests container with `--network host` option.
2. Start the e2e tests container with `--add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway` — this makes the good `localhost` accessible under `host.docker.internal`.

Unfortunately 1. does not work on docker for Mac, so developers using MacBooks could not run e2e tests. We are limited to 2., which means each backend API request needs to go to `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost`, which means another `environment-*.ts` and another frontend build.

### Is there a way to access a single build of an angular app on both `localhost` and from within a locally running docker container?

I tried to edit `/etc/hosts` on my computer to see if I can map `localhost` to any IP address I want. This way, I would map localhost in the `/etc/hosts` of the e2e tests' docker image to the IP address of `host.docker.internal`. However, this seems not to work. I can map a bogus domain to the IP address of google and it works, but if I map `localhost`, nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried using something like `/api` (no protocol, host, port -- just absolute path)? That's how I configure my Angular apps in multi-domain environment, everything works fine so far.

Answer (score 1):

read this post
[Nginx with Angular and Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72508625/nginx-with-angular-and-spring-boot)

#### Config in Angular

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  endpoint: 'http://server-name:8887',
  apiUrl: '/'
};
```