# Deploying angular-spring boot (with eureka) on nginx

Tags: angular, spring-boot, nginx, netflix-eureka

I am trying to deploy an application on a nginx web server. The app uses two Spring Boot microservices (on ports 8081 and 8083) which register with eureka (on port 8761) and transfer data between my Angular frontend and a postgresql server. All except postgres are on the same server. I am very green. Basically, I understand that I should set up a proxy in my nginx.conf file, perhaps like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72508625/nginx-with-angular-and-spring-boot/76293249#76293249). Does each of the microservices need to be set up in my nginx.conf? If so, how might it look? I am very green, so your patience and help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried proxy forwarding for Angular, which I thought would make the entire app functional by forwarding requests to the domain to the port where Angular is running, but this didn't seem to work. I then ran 'ng build' and told nginx where to find the dist files for Angular. This made the frontend visible, but it was disconnected from the api. Now, it seems like I need to write a nginx.conf file similar to that in the link above, but I don't know how.

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events 
{
     worker_connections 768;
     # multi_accept on;
}

http 
{
include    /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    upstream springboot
    {
        server example.com:8081;
        server example.com:8083;
    }

    server
    {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name example.com;

        location / 
    {
                proxy_pass https://example.com:4200;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

       location /api
        {
          proxy_pass    http://springboot;
          proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;        
        }

    }
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
}
```